# Assigning shell command output to a variable in ROOT

Tags: shell, root-framework

I am executing a shell command in my ROOT code using `gSystem` which returns an `int`, as seen here [gSystem->Exec()](https://root.cern.ch/root/html/TSystem.html#TSystem:Exec). But when I try to assign the output to a in code variable the assignment doesn't happen.

```
int low_edge = 0;
low_edge = gSystem->Exec("ls ./folder | egrep -o '[0-9]{3,3}' | head -1");
```

I have tried also `gSystem->Exec("ls ./folder | egrep -o '[0-9]{3,3}' | head -1") >> low_edge`, but it didn't work out.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of gSystem->Exec() is 0 or -1 depending on if the command was successful.

What you want is:

[TString    GetFromPipe(const char* command)](https://root.cern.ch/root/html/TSystem.html#TSystem:GetFromPipe)

```
TString the_output=gSystem->GetFromPipe("ls ./folder | egrep -o '[0-9]{3,3}' | head -1");
```

should work, you just need to convert TString to int.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. Just added `AtoI()` from `TString` to convert to integer.